# Getting a GUI to appear when I click on a part roblox studio

Tags: lua, roblox

I was trying to make a game in Roblox studio, and I wanted to make a GUI appear when I click on a part. So far, it will appear, and I also have a button to close it that works. After I close it, for some reason, I can't open it again. Any ideas? Here is my code:

Opening code:

```
function Clicked(Plr)
    Plr.PlayerGui.ScreenGuisword.Frame.Visible=true
end

script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(Clicked)
```

Closing code:

```
script.Parent.MouseButton1Down:Connect(function()


    script.Parent.Parent.Visible = false
end)
```

**Keep in mind that the opening code is a part, and the closing code is a GUI button**

Comment: Without seeing the hierarchy of the objects, it's hard to give a definitive answer. But does `script.Parent.Parent` refer to the `ScreenGuisword.Frame`?

Comment: Yes the second script is a child of a child of the frame. Sorry of my lack of knowledge, I only know the basics of python and so could kind of connect the dots for lua

Answer (score -1):

You dont have to do that, you can just do something like this:

`script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()`
`Plr.PlayerGui.ScreenGuisword.Frame.Visible = true`
`script.Parent.MouseClick:Connect(function()`
`script.Parent.Parent.Visible = false`
end)`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Answers should solve the question but yours does not. You should edit your answer and make it solve the question. (It's probably not possible though, since it's probably a problem with something not specified in the question.)